# draggable disappears on start dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make floating panel with

```
var self = this;

this.$widget = (function() {
    var $panel = $("#tmpl-float-panel").tmpl({
        title : title
    });

    //close on click on cross
    $panel.find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").click(function() {
        self.hide();
    });

    $panel.draggable({
        containment : "parent",
        handle : "div.ui-dialog-titlebar",
        opacity : 0.75
    }).appendTo($container);

    return $panel;
})();
```

later I insert content with

```
this.$widget.find(".ui-dialog-content").append($content);
```

And here's jquery template used to build panel:

```
<script id="tmpl-float-panel" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="ui-widget ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget-content float-panel no-select">
        <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
            <span class="ui-dialog-title">${title}</span>
            <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">
                <span class="ui-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here's the question. When I'm trying to drag the panel (clicking on title bar and moving mouse), the whole widget disappears. Can someone tell me why?

**UPD:** on chrome it do not disappear on click, but somewhy it takes all possible width.

here's html wrapping floating panel:

```
<div id="idA">
<div id="idB">
<!-- here I have panels and other divs -->
</div>
</div>
```

in CSS I have

```
#idA {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#idB {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hard to help you without a fiddle.

Comment: Does it still disappear if you comment out the close function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lack of a jsfiddle I've created one, based on the code that you've provided.

Within the jsfiddle, the panel works as expected in all browsers that I've tested with (including FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera).

I think your issue might be related to the fact that you haven't properly defined the jqueryui  dialog close button in your jQuery template and a click on the title bar may have been misinterpreted as a click event on ".ui-dialog-titlebar-close".
In my jsfiddle I've defined:

```
<a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>
</a>
```

which might make the difference.

Here is the [**link to the jsfiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/yCfEa/3/)

Comment: Thank you!!!! your solution is better then mine (adding `style="display: inline-block"`).

Answer (score 1):

Try appending first then calling draggable and resizable:

$panel.appendTo($container).resizable().draggable();

Comment: that does not seem to help(((

Answer (score 1):

I had that once and the problem was that a parent div had the css property `position: absolute`. The effect was that the item was put on the bottom right screen corner the moment I started to drag it around. So first you thought it had disappeared but if you dragged it towards top-left it would come up.

Comment: Thank you. But that does not help :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `display: inline-block` to float panel

```
<script id="tmpl-float-panel" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div style="display: inline-block" class="ui-widget ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget-content float-panel no-select">
        <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix">
            <span class="ui-dialog-title">${title}</span>
            <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#" role="button">
                <span class="ui-icon"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Any ideas of more elegant solution?

Comment: can you please comment on the answers that have been provided? Does my provided jsfiddle answer your question why the widget disappeared in your code (and does NOT disappear in the jsfiddle)?